# characterizing an operator with projection whose spectrum is contained in $\{-1,1\}$

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra and  $\sigma$ denote the spectrum. I want to show that if $\sigma (A)\subseteq \{-1,+1\}$  for $A\in \mathcal{A}$ then there is a projection $P$ such that $A=2P-I$. Is this true?

Comment: By scaling and translating you can assume that the spectrum is contained in $\{0,1\}$ and try to conclude that it is a projection, no? That makes for a nicer statemeent.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez can you explain more?

Comment: Replace $A$ by $B=(A+I)/2$, and see what the statement you want to prove becomes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez is commutative necessary?

Comment: For what? Notice that, as the spectrum of an element $A$ of the algebra will not change it you replace the algebra by a subalgbra which contains $A$, you can replace $\mathcal A$ by the closed $C^*$-subalgebra generated by $A$, and *that* is a commutative $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez $A$ sould be normal!

Comment: Oh. Right! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Let ${\mathcal A}=B(H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Let $0\ne Q \in B(H)$ be a quasinilpotent operator, i.e., $\sigma(Q)=\{ 0\}$, and let $A=I+Q$. Then $\sigma(A)=\{ 1\}\subseteq \{ -1,1\}$. If there were a projection $P\in B(H)$ such that $A=2P-I$, then
we would have $Q=2P-2I$, where $I$ is the identity operator, and consequently 
$$ Q^2=4P^2-8P+4I=-2(2P-2I). $$
It would follow that
$$ Q^2+2Q=0$$
which is impossible for a non-zero quasinilpotent operator $Q$ because $Q+2I$ is invertible.

Comment: $Q=2P-I$? or $Q=2P-2I$? Line 5!

Comment: @Vahid Thanks! I have fixed the mistake.